# sliding more than 1 img at one time using animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create slider for partner logos. I have script which is moving one element.
How to collect all images and moving it all in one time?

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var w = $("#partners").width();
   $(".img").css({left: w-50});
   var f = function(){
      $(".img").animate({left: 0},5000,function(){
         $(".img").css({left: w-50});
         f();
      });
   };
   f();
});
```

My img is moving to end of document and f() is calling again(something like a loop).
I need to do it with more than one image.

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/waBS3/1)***

The code you are using is set to work on a class. So just mark other elements with that class to animate multiple elements. Here is a simple example (updated to step the animation):

html

```
<div id="partners" style="width:50px;"></div>
<div class="img">Me</div>
<div class="img">Mini Me</div>
<div class="img">Mini Me Me</div>
<div class="img">Mini Me Me Me</div>
```

css

```
.img{
    position:relative;
}
```

js - In order to step the animation, keep track of an index and mod it by length to make sure it wraps around (`i` in this case)

```
var w = $("#partners").width();
$(".img").css({left: w-50});
var f = function(i){
  i = i % $(".img").length;
  $(".img").eq(i).animate({left: 0},750,function(){
     $(".img").eq(i).css({left: w-50});
     f(i+1);
  });
};
f(0);
```

Comment: Its good but when first .img reaches the end all is moving to start. I need to treat each .img as another object. When one reached end of document it should be moving to start, but rest of them should going on.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put them all in a div and move that instead? For instance

```
<div id="imagesmoving"> <img></img>  <img></img> <img></img> <img></img> <img></img></div>
```

Comment: You don't have to use `</img> to close the tag. Just use `<img />`. A good answer however.